# How do I abort a modal box closing?

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog

I'm trying to validate some data before I allow a modal box to close, but it seems to close before the validation takes place. This is my code

```
Public Class my_popup

Inherits Form

Dim result = Me.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.OK Then
   If key = Nothing Then
      If last_name.Text <> "" Then
         MessageBox.Show("The user is not in the database.")
        ' Abort closing and leave dialog open.
      End If
   Else
     save_it()
   End If
End If

End Class
```

When the message box shows up, then modal form is already closed. How do I keep this from happening?

Comment: _Me.ShowDialog()_ ? In which method of which class are you calling this?

Comment: I edited it to show the class.

Comment: You just put the MessageBox.Show() call in the wrong spot.  It can only run *after* the dialog is closed.  Put it where it belongs, in the OK button Click event handler.  Don't set the DialogResult property when you are unhappy.

Comment: And you can loop it until results are being ok. if not reopen it

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit odd. Usually a modal dialog is called from a parent form that requires some input and wait until the modal dialog has completed its work. If you need some kind of validation in the modal dialog and keep the modal dialog open if the validation fails then you should write something like this

In the calling form:

```
Using frm = new my_popup()
   if frm.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
      ..... if we enter here the validation is OK...
   End If
End Using
```

then, in the `my_popup` class, usually you have an OK button (for this example called buttonOK) that is set as the AcceptButton for the form and its property DialogResult is set to DialogResult.OK.

Then, when you click the OK button, you write your validation, in the event handler of the button

```
Protected Sub buttonOK_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles buttonOK.Click

      If last_name.Text <> "" Then
          MessageBox.Show("The user is not in the database.")
          ' Abort closing and leave dialog open.
          Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
      Else
          Dim saved = save_it()
          if saved = false Then
              MessageBox.Show(....fail to save....)
              Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.None
          End If
      End If
End Sub
```

The key point here is to set the property DialogResult of the my_popup form to DialogResult.None. This will block the automatic closing of the form and your user could type the necessary fixes to the input....

Comment: OK, Thanks. I'll do that.